# How to pass the enum value from a class decorated with Custom Attribute which is also Enum?

Tags: c#

This is the first time I am writing a simple custom attribute. Let me first show that what I have done

**providers.cs**

```
public enum Providers
    {
        Employee,
        Product
    };
```

**MyCustomAttribute.cs**

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class) ]
    public class ServiceProvider : System.Attribute
    {
        private Providers provider;        

        public ServiceProvider(Providers provider)
        {
            this.provider = provider;            
        }

        public Providers CustomProvider
        {
            get
            {
                return provider;
            }
        }
    }
```

**A.cs**

```
[ServiceProvider(Providers.Employee)]
    public class A
    { 
        public void SomeMethod()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Dataclass.GetRecord("Employee"));
        }
    }
```

**B.cs**

```
[ServiceProvider(Providers.Product)]
    public class B
    {
        public void SomeMethod()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Dataclass.GetRecord("Product"));
        }
    }
```

**dataclass.cs**

```
public static class Dataclass
    {
        public static string GetRecord(string key)
        {
            return InfoDictionary()[key];
        }

        private static Dictionary<string, string> InfoDictionary()
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            dictionary.Add("Employee", "This is from Employees");
            dictionary.Add("Product", "This is from proucts");
            return dictionary;
        }
    }
```

At present, I  am hard-coding the "keys" from the individual Classes viz. A and B.

What I am looking for is that, if I decorate my Class A with `[ServiceProvider(Providers.Employee)]` then the **GetRecord** method should get me the Employee Related Value.

For Class B, if I decorate with **[ServiceProvider(Providers.Product)]**, I should be able to get Product related value.

**N.B.~**  I know that it is just a simple thing to achieve by passing a Enum also and converting to string, but as I said I am learning the Custom Attribute, so I want to do it in that way only.

Please let me know if it is possible or not and if "Yes" then how can I achieve this?

Comment: Your `Dataclass` doesn't use attributes or doing anything with the other classes. It's very unclear how it's all meant to work together... (If you'd got a value of `Dictionary<Providers, Type>` that would make more sense...)

Comment: Respected Sir, since it is just an example so, I am using the DataClass. My main focus is how can I pass the Class level Decorated Value  to Dataclass.GetRecord("Employee"). I mean , if I decorate by [ServiceProvider(Providers.Employee)], the method should be able to recognize the Employee service.Similarly if I do, [ServiceProvider(Providers.Product)],, only the product service will be invoked. The dataclass is just an example here.

Comment: But it's not a *useful* example, as it doesn't seem to be related to what you're doing. Why would you pass a string at all? Why not `DataClass.GetRecord(Providers.Employee)`? And heck, where is the benefit of using an attribute on the class rather than just passing it as an argument directly? I'm sorry, I'm just not seeing the point of this...

Comment: Actually I am implementing Provider Model.var sqlRes = MyBaseProviderManager.Providers["EmployeeProvider"].GetProviderInformation();
            var xmlRes = MyBaseProviderManager.Providers["ProductProvider"].GetProviderInformation(); It is working fine. But my intention is that, suppose if developer just decorate the class with Provider.Employee, then the EmployeeProvider will be called.So like Product Provider. Though the existing way is working fine, I want to try in a different way.

Comment: Why is it any better to specify that as an attribute than it is to specify it as an  argument? What do you expect to gain? (The implementation be more complicated, to start with, which speaks against it - you should have some concrete *benefit* in mind.)

Comment: You have a bad example. You can do it much cleaner and more type safe with interfaces. Say ICanGetEmployeeRecord and ICanGetProductRecord. You can still use Reflection to discover all classes that implement those interfaces. But now you can be sure that those classes provide methods GetEmployeeRecord and GetProductRecord respectively. With attributes compiler cannot help you enforce that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You access custom attributes through reflection

```
var type = typeof(A);
var attributes = type.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ServiceProvider),inherit:false);
```

That would give you an array of all service provider attributes for class A.

Your example doesn't really show how you want to apply it but to fit with what you have you could have an extension method

```
public static class ClassExtenstions
{
    public static Providers? GetServiceProvider<T>(this T cls) where T : class
    {
        var attribute = typeof(T).GetCustomAttributes(typeof (ServiceProvider), inherit: false).FirstOrDefault() as ServiceProvider;
        return attribute != null ? attribute.CustomProvider : (Providers?)null;
    }
}
```

And in your class you would use it as

```
[ServiceProvider(Providers.Employee)]
public class A
{ 
    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        var provider = this.GetServiceProvider();
        Console.WriteLine(Dataclass.GetRecord(provider.ToString()));
    }
}
```